# How do I input this system into maple?

Tags: math, system, maple

How to input such system 
[image]
into maple so that it would solve it?

BTW we some part of system will be given to us,, which we do not know certently - may be some Ai's may be some  Bi's as constants. we do not know how much constants we will get. And we would need from given constants get a soltion for other a's and b's. in real life we will be provided with s as a constant but I hoped for general solution=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see for k = 1

The first equation becomes:

```
 (1)  a0 + a1 = 0
```

The second one:

```
 (2)  a1 - b0 - b1 = 0
```

The third one

```
 (3)  a1 - 2 (b1) = 0   (for n=2)
```

and

```
 (4)  a1 - 3 (b1) = 0   (for n=3)
```

Subtracting (3) from (4) you see that b1 == 0

From (3), if b1=0, then a1=0 also

And from (1) and (2) then a0 and b0 are also 0.

So, at least for k=1 there are not non-trivial solutions. It seems that something else is needed as a condition for the problem.

HTH!

Comment: my point actually was that we could be given any part of system - meaning some of Ai's and  Bi's as constants. we do not know how much constants we will get.

Comment: @Kabumbus Could you give some info about the problem? Where it come from?